# Is there a way to increase the zoom on layers above 18 with Folium?

Tags: python, zooming, folium

I use Folium with Python and the maximum zoom level is 18.
I wonder if anyone has found a solution to increase the zoom level above this max value (even without any layer)?

```
mapping = folium.Map([x, y], 
                     zoom_start=18, # zoom_start=18 is the max zoom)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max_zoom`, which controls the maximum level of zoom and by default is set to `18`.

```py
mapping = folium.Map([x, y], zoom_start = 19, max_zoom = 19)
```

However, the maximum of a "working zoom level" depends on the source of map tiles. For Open Street Map, the maximum zoom level it supports is `19`. If you zoom beyond that in folium, you will just get blank background instead of a zoomed map.